# Programatically sort a merged view by a row value

Tags: views, 9

I am using the following `hook_views_pre_render` to merge 2 views_data_export views.

```
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'commerce_orders' && $view->current_display == 'data_export_1') {
    $first_extra_results_view = Views::getView('commerce_orders');
    $first_extra_results_view->setDisplay('data_export_2');
    $first_extra_results_view->execute();
    $first_extra_results_view->result;
    $view->result = array_merge($view->result, $first_extra_results_view->result);

  }
}
```

Both of the views are sorted by order_number, but array_merge is just stacking them on one another (as expected).

```
$view order_1
$view order_2
$first_extra_results_view order_1
$first_extra_results_view order_2
```

I would like to know how to take the new `$view->result` and re-apply the sort criteria so that the output of the `$view->result` would be this:

```
$view order_1
$first_extra_results_view order_1
$view order_2
$first_extra_results_view order_2
```

I am able to get the order number for each result, but I don't know how to sort the view results by those order numbers:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
  $order_number = $value->commerce_order_order_number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work this out quite simply.
I put the `array_merge()` into a `$results` variable:

```
$results = array_merge($view->result, $first_extra_results_view->result);
```

To get the `$order_number` for each of the `$results`, I used [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$order_number = array_column($results, 'commerce_order_order_number');
```

Then to sort the `$results` by `$order_number` I used [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).:

```
array_multisort($order_number, SORT_DESC, $results);
```

I did also have to re-sort the entire array for some reason, but all in all this is what I came up with:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'commerce_orders' && $view->current_display == 'data_export_1') {
    $first_extra_results_view = Views::getView('commerce_orders');
    $first_extra_results_view->setDisplay('data_export_2');
    $first_extra_results_view->execute();
    $first_extra_results_view->result;
    $results = array_merge($view->result, $first_extra_results_view->result);

    // Sort the rows by order number.
    $order_number = array_column($results, 'commerce_order_order_number');
    array_multisort($order_number, SORT_DESC, $results);

    // Sort the rows so that shipping items are back on the bottom.
    krsort($results);
    $view->result = $results;
  }
}
```